# how to fix get_dummies from training to test data?

Tags: python

I have the dataframe and did the get_dummies on categorical columns, so new columns were generated with names as "columnName_cellValues" for each categories of every categorical columns and build a model and saved it.

```
#Load data
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv',sep=',',decimal='.',header=0)
#encode target column
df['class'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['class'])
#filter categorical column names
cat_columns = df.dtypes[df.dtypes == "object"].index 
#get_dummies on it
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cat_columns, drop_first=True)

Now built the model say randomForest and pickled it
```

Later

```
I load the model and got a test data which is only one record, Here categorical columns will have one of the category, so to do the predict

How should I map the column names of the model and the test data? Because here I don't have the training data, I have only model and test data.
```

Example: training data has a column "COLOR" with red, green, blue as values, when we do get dummies we get 3 columns as COLOR_red, COLOR_green, COLOR_blue.

Now on the test data, if I have "COLOR" column with value "red", I need to create a column in test_data as COLOR_red and assign value as 1 and other 2 columns with zeros, How should I do this for multiple columns with multiple categories?

In order of using OneHotEncoder

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=cat_columns[0],sparse=False)
df = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df)
```

I am getting following Error

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:392: DeprecationWarning: The 'categorical_features' keyword is deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.
  "use the ColumnTransformer instead.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-b7547a4fe6b8>", line 1, in <module>
    QBE_clean = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 511, in fit_transform
    self._handle_deprecations(X)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 396, in _handle_deprecations
    sel[np.asarray(self.categorical_features)] = True

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: My rule of thumb is that one should apply `pd.get_dummies` if and only if you have _all_ the data (train, test, ...) in advance so that data are transformed with a consistency. In your case, use [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in order to _learn_ and _reapply_ the consistency from one data to the other.

Comment: I am having troubles with OneHotEncoder, getting Error as IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: In order for others (and me) to fully help you, please post some sample of your data, and your expected output, and if you are getting errors, traceback of that error as well :). Right now it is extremely hard to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Edited the Main Question for OneHotEncoder